# C# How to close Autocad pop-up when saving an XRef programmatically?

Tags: .net, api, autocad, autocad-plugin, dwg

I am new in using AutoCAD and I am trying to work with its API in C#.

At some point, I am trying to send a list of commands to save an external reference without the interference of the user.

```
SendCommand("_-REFEDIT OK All Yes REFCLOSE Save ");
```

But a blocking pop-up (dialog box) appears right after, pop-up image:

[image: pop-up image]

It can be closed only by clicking on it.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to avoid this pop-up appearing or to close it programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried like this?
`SendCommand("_-REFEDIT OK All Yes REFCLOSE Save\n");`
`SendCommand("Save\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated setting the [`FILEDIA`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-99736BD7-E60E-4F4A-83F7-436B6F9C67A1-htm.html) variable to `0` before running the command?

To quote:

> *Does not display dialog boxes*. You can still request a file dialog box to appear by entering a tilde (~) in response to the Command prompt.

Comment: Already tried to set FILEDIA to 0, but it doesn't change anything for this dialog box